# Windows script to enable TPM

Tags: windows, vbscript, tpm

I am looking to write a script that will enable a TPM chip and BitLocker in Windows, with VBScript.  I am new to VBScript and Windows scripting in general.
One part that I seem to be hitting a snag on is having my script start up again after a reboot.

For example, to enable the TPM chip a reboot is required to turn on the chip, and then a second reboot is required to take ownership of the TPM chip.  A third reboot would be required to enable BitLocker.

How do I have the script start up again after each reboot to move to the next step?  And is VBscript the best choice to accomplish this task?

Comment: First, I doubt that you can enable a TPM from within a running OS. The TPM needs to be enabled in the BIOS. Second, for taking ownership of a TPM no reboot is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
rem Make sure you applied the appropriate policies before activating!

manage-bde -tpm -TurnOn
manage-bde -tpm -TakeOwnership PASSWORD
manage-bde -on C: -RecoveryPassword -SkipHardwareTest
```

The TPM must be enabled in the BIOS first, though.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft already provides a VBScript for enabling BitLocker. You can learn more about it here:

[Enabling BitLocker by using a WMI script](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd875527%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

And the script itself is available from here:

[BitLocker Deployment Sample Resources](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/bdedeploy/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=3205)